# Getting "Command not found" when using pscp command

Tags: ssh, sftp, putty, scp, pscp

I am transferring a project folder to AWS instance using PuTTY pscp.

I am able to connect using .ppk public keys file and `ssh` command opened successfully and logged-in.

Here I am using command to transfer folder:

```
pscp -r -i C:\path-to-my-keys\converted-pem-keys.ppk d:\MyDevelopment\myproj ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/ec2-user/myproj
```

It shows:

```
 pscp: Command not found.
```

Path to PuTTY folder is set in Environment variables. Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*"Command not found"* is a common *nix shell error message. What indicates that you probably type the `pscp` command in PuTTY (remote) terminal.

But `pscp` is Windows application. You have to type your `pscp` command in (local) Windows console (`cmd.exe` or PowerShell).